# How to exit a while loop with a keystroke in C?

Tags: c++, c, while-loop

I want to have user press the space key to jump out of the while loop.

For example:

```
while ( some condition )

{

printf ("Press space bar to continue...");

}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Reading a single key-stroke (without the return key and such) requires platform specific code, but you haven't told us what platform you're using. It's also not clear whether you want the read to block -- do you want to wait for the user to press a key, or do you want to execute some code, check of a key stroke now and then, and quit executing that loop when the user presses the key?

Comment: sorry, its linux. actually enter key is ok too

Comment: Are you building console or window (GUI) application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean the following as long as a spacebar followed by the enter key is acceptable given your comments above.

```
char input = 0;
while( input != ' ' )
{ 
  printf("Press space bar to continue...\n");
  scanf("%c",&input);
}
```

Or if you prefer, without hitting the enter key:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char input = 0;
  while( input != ' ' )
  { 
    printf("Press space bar to continue...\n");
    input = getch();
  }
}
```

**This worked on my msysgit bash shell.**  BUT, some people will insist that it work on Linux as well.  Which is fine I guess, I love Linux, but I said the above solution worked on **msysgit**.  The following works on my, let me be specific, Oracle VM for Ubuntu 10.10.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char input = 0;
  while( input != ' ' )
  { 
    printf("Press space bar to continue...\n");
    input = mygetch();
  }
}

int mygetch(void)
{
  struct termios oldt, newt;
  int ch;
  tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldt );
  newt = oldt;
  newt.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
  tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt );
  ch = getchar();
  tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt );
  return ch;
}
```

The `mygetch` came from [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/503640-getch-linux).

Comment: this will not work... it requires a spacebar followed by an enter key.

Comment: getch() is a curses function and will not work the way you've described it.

Answer (score 1):

Capturing keystrokes under most platforms requires you to access the console directly. Typically there are libraries available to help you with that. Low-level libraries are termcap (which is derived from terminal capabilities) libraries.  There is a "portable" layer on top of termcap called curses. Linux uses the GNU version which is called ncurses and is actually available on a multitude of platforms.

Curses is extensively documented, you can start a tutorial using

```
$ man ncurses
```

Your problem requires steps to initialize the console and set up keystroke reader. There are several ways to achieve your desired effect.

I am posting a working example for you to play with. It shows some basic ideas in curses:

```
/* file: curses_ex1.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>

const char rotary[4] = "/-\\|";
int main() {
    WINDOW *w;
    int i = 0;
    w = initscr();
    if ( w == NULL ) {
        return -1; /* unable to initialize curses */
    }
    timeout(500); /* do not block */ 
    mvprintw(0, 0, "Press space bar to break out of the loop.");
    noecho();
    for(i = 0; ; i++) { /* no condition so loops forever */
        int c; 
        mvaddch(0, 42, rotary[i%4]); /* display rotator */
        c = getch();   /* get a character */
        if ( c == ' ') 
            break;
        if ( c != ERR ) { /* not a space but another valid key */
            mvprintw(1, 0, "You need to press a space for me to stop (you pressed `%c')", c);
        }
    }
    endwin(); 
    return 0;
}
```

To compile it:

```
cc -o curses_ex1 curses_ex1.c -lcurses
```

Answer (score -2):

Make a variable x = 1, put that in the condition, when they press space bar, set x to 2.

Comment: @eastboundr That is a completely different question from the one you asked, and the comments of this answer are not where you should be asking it.

Comment: err no it does not achieve the desired effect of "Press space bar to continue"